# How does the IBM MobileFirst server know if it is in "production" or "sandbox" mode for APNS notifications?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, push, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm looking at the [MobileFirst Platform 7.1 push notification setup instructions](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-0/notifications/push-notifications-hybrid-applications/), and am trying to debug an issue with an MFP server where it seems to be connected to the wrong Apple backend server (sandbox where it should be production).

To clarify: how does the MFP *server* know if it is in "sandbox" or "production" mode? Is it purely based on which of the two `.p12` files (`apns-certificate-sandbox.p12` and `apns-certificate-production.p12`) exist in the `.wlapp` file? What happens if both of them are present?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is based on the name of the certificate. It either ends with "sandbox" or "production".

Comment: OK, do you know what happens if both are present?

Comment: Really really bad things. Keep only one.

Comment: I guessed. I'm debugging the problem from the other end which is what happens if someone's already done that :) But you answered enough for what I need, thx.